# Change Primary ID in laravel Migration

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm creating a table where I want to use the ID from this table "menu_items" to be added in another table

Table one: menu_items

```
Schema::create('menu_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('menu_level_item_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('menu_item_name');
    $table->string('menu_item_desc');
```

Table 2 products

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->string('product_desc');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('menu_level_item_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My aim of doing this is that I can then create a relationship between the 2 tables as they have the same key?

Is there a different approach I can take? Should I create a unique key when creating a menu item and then add this to the second table?

Thank you.

Comment: You dont need to create the same key on both table. If you wish you can create same key also. Suppose, you have a table `users` and one is `products`. One user has many products, so on `products` table you can define a relation with `users` table. This key can be `user_id` or anything.

Comment: this might not be the correct way to expect laravel to create relations for you, for that you have to define relationships in laravel model of two tables and pass the correct column names to connect them through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Laravel Eloquent do the key handling. When you have two tables which both has as key the name id, this is not a problem. Name the keys in the relation table just like this

```
table1_id
table2_id
```

Laravel will handle this in Eloquent. You are also able to name the two columns in the relation table to what ever you want. You could define it for the relation in Eloquent. E.g.

```
public function otherModel () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\OtherModel', 'table_name', 'this_model_id', 'other_model_id');
}
```

Please have a look into:
[Laravel Relationship Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('menu_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('menu_item_name');
    $table->string('menu_item_desc');
    table->timestamp();
  });


Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('product_name');
        $table->string('product_desc');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('menu_level_item_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('menu_level_item_id')->references('id')->on('menu_items');
    });
```